# Using lists of types to specify types conversion order for operations

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I want a mechanism for specifying arbitrary order of type conversion for arbitrary set of types for each operation on that types (separately).

For example, let's have set of types `Bool`, `Date`, `Number`, `String` and operations `isEqual` and `isLess`.

For `isEqual` I would like to have order `Bool -> Date -> Number -> String` and for `isLess` - `String -> Bool -> Date -> Number`, given that not all possible conversions exist - `Bool` can be converted to `Number` and to `String`, while `String` - to `Date` and `Number`, and `Number` - to `Bool`, `Date` and `String`.

So, if `isEqual` is given two values - `Bool` and `Number`, it should convert them to two `Numbers`. And if `isLess` is given `String` and `Bool` it should convert them again to two `Numbers`, while given `String` and `Date` - to two `Dates`.

---

I've devised a solution based on list of types (types used differ from example above, but the idea is the same):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using std::is_convertible;

// toy set of types
typedef bool Bool;
typedef std::time_t Date;
typedef int Number;
typedef float Float;
typedef std::string String;
struct Any {
  long value;
  Any() = default;
  Any(Bool b) : value(b) {}
  Any(Date d) : value(d) {}
  Any(Number n) : value(n) {}
  Any(Float f) : value(f) {}
  Any(const String &s) : value(std::stol(s)) {}
};

bool operator<(const Any &lhs, const Any &rhs) { return lhs.value < rhs.value; }

// predicate negation
template <class T>
using predicate_not = std::integral_constant<bool, !T::value>;

// list of types implementation
template <class... Ts> struct type_list {};

using empty_list = type_list<>;

template <class L> using is_empty = std::is_same<L, empty_list>;

// extract head and tail from list
template <class L> struct uncons;

template <template <class...> class L, class T, class... Ts>
struct uncons<L<T, Ts...>> {
  using head = T;
  using tail = L<Ts...>;
};

template <class L> using head = typename uncons<L>::head;
template <class L> using tail = typename uncons<L>::tail;

// get head from non-empty list or substitute type from empty list
template <class L, class T> struct maybe_head_impl { using type = head<L>; };

template <template <class...> class L, class T> struct maybe_head_impl<L<>, T> {
  using type = T;
};

template <class L, class T>
using maybe_head = typename maybe_head_impl<L, T>::type;

// prepending list
template <class L, class... T> struct push_front_impl;

template <template <class...> class L, class... U, class... T>
struct push_front_impl<L<U...>, T...> {
  using type = L<T..., U...>;
};

template <class L, class... T>
using push_front = typename push_front_impl<L, T...>::type;

// filtering list by predicate
template <template <class> class P, class L> struct filter_impl;

template <template <class> class P, class L>
using filter = typename filter_impl<P, L>::type;

template <template <class> class P, template <class...> class L>
struct filter_impl<P, L<>> {
  using type = L<>;
};

template <template <class> class P, template <class...> class L, class T,
          class... Ts>
struct filter_impl<P, L<T, Ts...>> {
  using _rest = filter<P, L<Ts...>>;
  using type =
      typename std::conditional<P<T>::value, push_front<_rest, T>, _rest>::type;
};

// skipping beginning of list by predicate
template <template <class> class P, class L> struct drop_while_impl;

template <template <class> class P, class L>
using drop_while = typename drop_while_impl<P, L>::type;

template <template <class> class P, template <class...> class L>
struct drop_while_impl<P, L<>> {
  using type = L<>;
};

template <template <class> class P, template <class...> class L, class T,
          class... Ts>
struct drop_while_impl<P, L<T, Ts...>> {
  using type = typename std::conditional<P<T>::value, drop_while<P, L<Ts...>>,
                                         L<T, Ts...>>::type;
};

// skipping beginning of list till specific element
template <class T, class L> struct drop_before_impl {
  template <class X> using _check = predicate_not<std::is_same<T, X>>;
  using type = drop_while<_check, L>;
};

template <class T, class L>
using drop_before = typename drop_before_impl<T, L>::type;

// check if element A is preceding element B in list
template <class A, class B, class L>
using is_before = std::integral_constant<
    bool,
    predicate_not<is_empty<drop_before<B, tail<drop_before<A, L>>>>>::value>;

// filtering types, to which specified type can be converted
template <class T, class L> struct filter_convertible_impl {
  template <class X> using _check = is_convertible<T, X>;
  using type = filter<_check, L>;
};

template <class T, class L>
using filter_convertible = typename filter_convertible_impl<T, L>::type;

// finding common type with regard to specified order of types    
template <class A, class B, class L> struct common_by_impl {
  using _b2a = filter_convertible<B, drop_before<A, L>>;
  using _a2b = filter_convertible<A, drop_before<B, L>>;
  using type = typename std::conditional<is_before<A, B, L>::value,
                                         maybe_head<_a2b, void>,
                                         maybe_head<_b2a, void>>::type;
};

template <class T, class L> struct common_by_impl<T, T, L> { using type = T; };

template <class A, class B, class L>
using common_by = typename common_by_impl<A, B, L>::type;

template <class L, class A, class B> bool isLess(A a, B b) {
  return common_by<A, B, L>(a) < common_by<A, B, L>(b);
}

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  using less_order = type_list<Bool, Date, Number, Float, String, Any>;
  cout << "Bool and Number are promoted to Number - "
       << std::is_same<Number, common_by<Bool, Number, less_order>>::value
       << endl;
  cout << "Number and Bool are promoted to Number - "
       << std::is_same<Number, common_by<Number, Bool, less_order>>::value
       << endl;
  cout << "Bool and Bool are promoted to Bool - "
       << std::is_same<Bool, common_by<Bool, Bool, less_order>>::value << endl;
  cout << "String and Date are promoted to Any - "
       << std::is_same<Any, common_by<String, Date, less_order>>::value << endl;
  Bool b(true);
  Number n(10);
  Float f(-0.5);
  String s("5");
  cout << b << " < " << n << " is " << isLess<less_order>(b, n) << endl;
  cout << b << " < " << f << " is " << isLess<less_order>(b, f) << endl;
  cout << b << " < " << s << " is " << isLess<less_order>(b, s) << endl;
  cout << n << " < " << s << " is " << isLess<less_order>(n, s) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

So, in short, I've implemented:

1. Classical type lists implemented with variadic templates
2. Some utility functions for working with such lists - get head and tail, push new element into list as new head
3. Method to filter list by predicate
4. Method to drop elements from beginning of a list that satisfy some predicate
5. Method to drop elements from beginning of a list till specified element
6. Method to check whether some element A precedes some other element B in a given list (implemented simply by checking if drop_before(B, tail(drop_before(A, list))) is not empty)
7. Method to filter types, to which specified type can be converted.
8. Method to find common type of two types given type list, which set order: just check which type come first in the list, drop all elements before the other type, filter the rest for types, to which the first one can be converted and if there are such types, return the first of them.

Using this it's simple to convert both operands in each operation to their common type with respect to specified type list.
I included several examples, all of which operate with single list `Bool, Date, Number, Float, String, Any`. Examples are:

1. Check if common type of Bool and Number is Number
2. Check if common type of Number and Bool is Number
3. Check if common type of Bool and Bool is Bool
4. Check if common type of String and Date is Any
5. Execute `<` operator on values `Bool(true)` and `Number(10)` using conversion of operands to common type
6. Execute `<` operator on values `Bool(true)` and `Float(-0.5)` using conversion of operands to common type
7. Execute `<` operator on values `Bool(true)` and `String(5)` using conversion of operands to common type
8. Execute `<` operator on values `Number(10)` and `String(5)` using conversion of operands to common type

It's compiling with g++ 4.8 and output is:

```
Bool and Number are promoted to Number - 1
Number and Bool are promoted to Number - 1
Bool and Bool are promoted to Bool - 1
String and Date are promoted to Any - 1
1 < 10 is 1
1 < -0.5 is 0
1 < 5 is 1
10 < 5 is 0
```

---

Could it be done better? What can be improved in this particular implementation?

Comment: I think this question belongs to SO, not CR.

Comment: @Walter Here I present a working solution and ask for feedback (ok, and for alternatives ideas too, but still...). Are you sure that on SO it would be more appropriate?